# HuggingFace BertForMaskedLM: Expected input batch_size (3200) to match target batch_size (16)

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers, multiclass-classification

Im working on a Multiclass Classification (Bengali Language Sentiment Analysis) on a pretrained Huggingface (BertForMaskedLM) model.

When the error occured I knew I have to change the label(output) size to match the input. But do not know how. Im adding the code snippents below.

```
MAX_LEN = 200
BATCH_SIZE = 16
```

**The pretrained models used:**

```
from transformers import BertForMaskedLM, BertTokenizer, pipeline
model = BertForMaskedLM.from_pretrained("sagorsarker/bangla-bert-base")
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("sagorsarker/bangla-bert-base")
```

**Code to make the pytorch dataset**:

```
class GPReviewDataset(Dataset):

def __init__(self, reviews, targets, tokenizer, max_len):
self.reviews = reviews
self.targets = targets
self.tokenizer = tokenizer
self.max_len = max_len

def __len__(self):
 return len(self.reviews)

def __getitem__(self, item):
 review = str(self.reviews[item])
 target = self.targets[item]

encoding = self.tokenizer.encode_plus(
  review,
  add_special_tokens=True,
  max_length=self.max_len,
  truncation = True,
  return_token_type_ids=False,
  padding='max_length',
  return_attention_mask=True,
  return_tensors='pt',
)

return {
  'review_text': review,
  'input_ids': encoding['input_ids'].flatten(),
  'attention_mask': encoding['attention_mask'].flatten(),
  'targets': torch.tensor(target, dtype=torch.long)
}
```

The input dimentions are:

```
print(data['input_ids'].shape)
print(data['attention_mask'].shape)
print(data['targets'].shape)
```

Which Outputs:

```
torch.Size([16, 200])
torch.Size([16, 200])
torch.Size([16])
```

**Training Class**

```
def train_epoch(model, data_loader, optimizer, device, scheduler, n_examples):

  model = model.train()    # tells your model that we are training
  losses = []
  correct_predictions = 0

  for d in data_loader:
    input_ids = d["input_ids"].to(device)
    attention_mask = d["attention_mask"].to(device)
    targets = d["targets"].to(device)

    loss, logits = model(
      input_ids=input_ids,
      attention_mask=attention_mask,
      labels = targets
    )
    
    #logits = classification scores befroe softmax
    #loss = classification loss
    
    logits = logits.view(-1, 28*28).detach().cpu().numpy()
    label_ids = targets.to('cpu').numpy()

    preds = np.argmax(logits, axis=1).flatten()   #returns indices of maximum logit
    targ = label_ids.flatten()

    correct_predictions += np.sum(preds == targ)

    losses.append(loss.item())
    loss.backward()   # performs backpropagation(computes derivates of loss w.r.t to parameters)
    nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), max_norm=1.0)  #clipping gradients so they dont explode
    optimizer.step()       #After gradients are computed by loss.backward() this makes the optimizer iterate over all parameters it is supposed to update and use internally #stored grad to update their values
    scheduler.step()    # this will make sure learning rate changes. If we dont provide this learning rate stays at initial value
    optimizer.zero_grad()     # clears old gradients from last step

  return correct_predictions / n_examples, np.mean(losses)
```

**Where the training Starts (*Where the error triggers*)**:

```
%%time
# standard block
# used accuracy as metric here
history = defaultdict(list)

best_acc = 0

for epoch in range(EPOCHS):

  print(f'Epoch {epoch + 1}/{EPOCHS}')
  print('-' * 10)

  train_acc, train_loss = train_epoch(model, train_data_loader, optimizer, device, scheduler, len(df_train))

  print(f'Train loss {train_loss} Accuracy {train_acc}')

  val_acc, val_loss = eval_model(model, valid_data_loader, device, len(df_valid))

  print(f'Val   loss {val_loss} Accuracy {val_acc}')
  print()

  history['train_acc'].append(train_acc)
  history['train_loss'].append(train_loss)
  history['val_acc'].append(val_acc)
  history['val_loss'].append(val_loss)

  if val_acc > best_acc:
    torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'best_model_state_a5.bin')
    best_acc = val_acc
```

**The error**:

```
Epoch 1/5
----------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-fb5a4d77ce37> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic('time', '', "# standard block\n# used accuracy as metric here\nhistory = defaultdict(list)\n\nbest_acc = 0\n\nfor epoch in range(EPOCHS):\n\n  print(f'Epoch {epoch + 1}/{EPOCHS}')\n  print('-' * 10)\n\n  train_acc, train_loss = train_epoch(model, train_data_loader, optimizer, device, scheduler, len(df_train))\n\n  print(f'Train loss {train_loss} Accuracy {train_acc}')\n\n  val_acc, val_loss = eval_model(model, valid_data_loader, device, len(df_valid))\n\n  print(f'Val   loss {val_loss} Accuracy {val_acc}')\n  print()\n\n  history['train_acc'].append(train_acc)\n  history['train_loss'].append(train_loss)\n  history['val_acc'].append(val_acc)\n  history['val_loss'].append(val_loss)\n\n  if val_acc > best_acc:\n    torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'best_model_state_a5.bin')\n    best_acc = val_acc\n\n# We are storing state of best model indicated by highest validation accuracy")

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in run_cell_magic(self, magic_name, line, cell)
   2115             magic_arg_s = self.var_expand(line, stack_depth)
   2116             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2117                 result = fn(magic_arg_s, cell)
   2118             return result
   2119 

<decorator-gen-53> in time(self, line, cell, local_ns)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/magic.py in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    186     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    187     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 188         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    189 
    190         if callable(arg):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/magics/execution.py in time(self, line, cell, local_ns)
   1191         else:
   1192             st = clock2()
-> 1193             exec(code, glob, local_ns)
   1194             end = clock2()
   1195             out = None

<timed exec> in <module>()

<ipython-input-39-948eefef2f8d> in train_epoch(model, data_loader, optimizer, device, scheduler, n_examples)
     13       input_ids=input_ids,
     14       attention_mask=attention_mask,
---> 15       labels = targets
     16     )
     17 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1049         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1050                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1051             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1052         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1053         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py in forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, token_type_ids, position_ids, head_mask, inputs_embeds, encoder_hidden_states, encoder_attention_mask, labels, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
   1327         if labels is not None:
   1328             loss_fct = CrossEntropyLoss()  # -100 index = padding token
-> 1329             masked_lm_loss = loss_fct(prediction_scores.view(-1, self.config.vocab_size), labels.view(-1))
   1330 
   1331         if not return_dict:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1049         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1050                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1051             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1052         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1053         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py in forward(self, input, target)
   1119     def forward(self, input: Tensor, target: Tensor) -> Tensor:
   1120         return F.cross_entropy(input, target, weight=self.weight,
-> 1121                                ignore_index=self.ignore_index, reduction=self.reduction)
   1122 
   1123 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in cross_entropy(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction)
   2822     if size_average is not None or reduce is not None:
   2823         reduction = _Reduction.legacy_get_string(size_average, reduce)
-> 2824     return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index)
   2825 
   2826 

ValueError: Expected input batch_size (3200) to match target batch_size (16).
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having exactly the same issue.